# Lazy loading of columns in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

Is it possible in sqlalchemy to lazy load a column? I have large BLOB column that I'm usually using but in some cases I don't want to load this specific column (while I'd like to have ORM object). Is it possible without adding separate table?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'

    book_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    summary = Column(String(2000))
    excerpt = deferred(Column(Text))
    photo = deferred(Column(Binary))
```

[Deferred Column Loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html?highlight=deferred%20loading)